# Export data and download file

Tags: apex, data-export, csv, record

I am exporting some data into csv from org and want to download that file. Now i can just send it to email. Any ideas?

```
List<Account > acclist = [Select id,name , CreatedDate , lastModifiedDate from Account limit 10];
string header = 'Record Id, Name , Created Date, Modified Date \n';
string finalstr = header ;
for(Account a: acclist)
{
       string recordString = '"'+a.id+'","'+a.Name+'","'+a.CreatedDate+'","'+a.LastModifiedDate +'"\n';
       finalstr = finalstr +recordString;
}
Messaging.EmailFileAttachment csvAttc = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
blob csvBlob = Blob.valueOf(finalstr);
string csvname= 'Account.csv';
csvAttc.setFileName(csvname);
csvAttc.setBody(csvBlob);
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email =new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
String[] toAddresses = new list<string> {'test@test.com'};
String subject ='Account CSV';
email.setSubject(subject);
email.setToAddresses( toAddresses );
email.setPlainTextBody('Account CSV ');
email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[]{csvAttc});
Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});
System.debug(csvAttc);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your email solution is working and that your question is "how can I get this information without needing to send it in an email?"

The easiest way would probably be to use the [Salesforce-provided Data Loader](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000324402&type=1) (or some similar tool). The "export" option allows you to choose an SObject, choose a location and name for the CSV file it'll generate, and then you could simply copy/paste your query into it.

Also easy would be to remove all of your EmailMessage related code and simply `system.debug(finalStr);`. If you run this in the developer console, right-click the log that it generates, and select "open raw log", it'll give you the entire string (instead of concatenating the output and/or putting timestamps and "USER DEBUG" at the start of every line).

Beyond that, you'd need to look at using something like a Visualforce page (if you want a button to click) or storing it as a `ContentDocument` (well, a `ContentDocumentVersion`).

Comment: Got it, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can create a Document file and redirect a user of the Visualforce page to download this file

```
List<Account > acclist = [Select id,name , CreatedDate , lastModifiedDate from Account limit 10];
string header = 'Record Id, Name , Created Date, Modified Date \n';
string finalstr = header ;
for(Account a: acclist)
{
       string recordString = '"'+a.id+'","'+a.Name+'","'+a.CreatedDate+'","'+a.LastModifiedDate +'"\n';
       finalstr = finalstr +recordString;
}
    Document o = new Document(
        FolderId = UserInfo.getUserId(),
        Name = 'Account.csv',
        Body = Blob.valueOf(finalstr )
    );
    insert o;
    return new PageReference('/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=' + o.Id);
```